# Row wise conditional comparisons

Tags: r, dplyr

I am looking at some antimicrobial resistance data but come across a problem. Very occasionally there are antibiotic sensitive/resistant mismatches across two separate antibiotics when there shouldn't be. In the reprex below, OXA (oxacillin) should always be congruent with FLC (flucloxacillin); we can see the second sample is congruent but not the first. This is almost certainly a data entry problem from when repeat testing was done and so the sample needs to be excluded.

I don't want NAs to be identified as mismatches either, as sometimes only one or other of OXA and FLC are tested.

I can conditionally check between these two different antibiotics if I pivot the data to a wide format and then back again but I am wondering if there is a way to do this conditional checking between rows in the long format, without pivoting backwards and forwards.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df <- tribble(
  ~id, ~organism, ~antibiotic, ~sensitivity,
  1, "STAUR", "FLC", "R",
  1, "STAUR", "OXA", "S",
  1, "STAUR", "VAN", "S",
  1, "STAUR", "CLI", "S",
  2, "STAUR", "FLC", "S",
  2, "STAUR", "OXA", "S",
  2, "STAUR", "VAN", "S",
  2, "STAUR", "CLI", "S",
  3, "STAUR", "FLC", "S",
  3, "STAUR", "OXA", NA,
  3, "STAUR", "VAN", "S",
  3, "STAUR", "CLI", "R",
  4, "STAUR", "FLC", NA,
  4, "STAUR", "OXA", "S",
  4, "STAUR", "VAN", "S",
  4, "STAUR", "CLI", "R"
)
  
df %>% 
  pivot_wider(
    id_cols = id:organism,
    names_from = antibiotic,
    values_from = sensitivity
  ) %>%
  mutate(mismatch = case_when(FLC != OXA ~ TRUE,
                              FLC == OXA | is.na(FLC) | is.na(OXA) ~ FALSE)) %>% 
  pivot_longer(cols = FLC:CLI,
               names_to = "antibiotic",
               values_to = "sensitivity")


#> # A tibble: 16 × 5
#>       id organism mismatch antibiotic sensitivity
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <lgl>    <chr>      <chr>      
#>  1     1 STAUR    TRUE     FLC        R          
#>  2     1 STAUR    TRUE     OXA        S          
#>  3     1 STAUR    TRUE     VAN        S          
#>  4     1 STAUR    TRUE     CLI        S          
#>  5     2 STAUR    FALSE    FLC        S          
#>  6     2 STAUR    FALSE    OXA        S          
#>  7     2 STAUR    FALSE    VAN        S          
#>  8     2 STAUR    FALSE    CLI        S          
#>  9     3 STAUR    FALSE    FLC        S          
#> 10     3 STAUR    FALSE    OXA        <NA>       
#> 11     3 STAUR    FALSE    VAN        S          
#> 12     3 STAUR    FALSE    CLI        R          
#> 13     4 STAUR    FALSE    FLC        <NA>       
#> 14     4 STAUR    FALSE    OXA        S          
#> 15     4 STAUR    FALSE    VAN        S          
#> 16     4 STAUR    FALSE    CLI        R
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-10 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Within each `id`, you can subset to the relevant antibiotics and test whether there’s more than one unique `sensitivity` value. If you use `dplyr::n_distinct()` with `na.rm = TRUE`, `NA` values won't be identified as mismatches.

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(
    mismatch = n_distinct(
        sensitivity[antibiotic %in% c("OXA", "FLC")], 
        na.rm = TRUE
      ) > 1, 
    .by = id
  )
#> # A tibble: 16 × 5
#>       id organism antibiotic sensitivity mismatch
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>       <lgl>   
#>  1     1 STAUR    FLC        R           TRUE    
#>  2     1 STAUR    OXA        S           TRUE    
#>  3     1 STAUR    VAN        S           TRUE    
#>  4     1 STAUR    CLI        S           TRUE    
#>  5     2 STAUR    FLC        S           FALSE   
#>  6     2 STAUR    OXA        S           FALSE   
#>  7     2 STAUR    VAN        S           FALSE   
#>  8     2 STAUR    CLI        S           FALSE   
#>  9     3 STAUR    FLC        S           FALSE   
#> 10     3 STAUR    OXA        <NA>        FALSE   
#> 11     3 STAUR    VAN        S           FALSE   
#> 12     3 STAUR    CLI        R           FALSE   
#> 13     4 STAUR    FLC        <NA>        FALSE   
#> 14     4 STAUR    OXA        S           FALSE   
#> 15     4 STAUR    VAN        S           FALSE   
#> 16     4 STAUR    CLI        R           FALSE
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-10 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, I don't think this will work as in reality there are about a dozen different antibiotics in the list and these others don't necessarily need to be congruent. It's the specifically comparing the sensitivity between two selected antibiotics on different rows which is key. Apologies I tried to keep the reprex as simple as possible. I will think about how to extend it slightly but so it is not too unwieldy.

Comment: thanks. excellent answer. was thinking if there was a "tidierverse" way of doing it without the base R subset can't think of one

Answer (score 1):

You could simply state the comparison logic in `by`.

```
> by(df, ~id, \(x) {
+   x$mismatch <- if (!any(is.na(x$sensitivity))) {
+     with(x, sensitivity[antibiotic == 'FLC'] != 
+            sensitivity[antibiotic == 'OXA'])
+   } else FALSE
+   x
+ }) |> do.call(what='rbind')
# A tibble: 16 × 5
      id organism antibiotic sensitivity mismatch
 * <dbl> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>       <lgl>   
 1     1 STAUR    FLC        R           TRUE    
 2     1 STAUR    OXA        S           TRUE    
 3     1 STAUR    VAN        S           TRUE    
 4     1 STAUR    CLI        S           TRUE    
 5     2 STAUR    FLC        S           FALSE   
 6     2 STAUR    OXA        S           FALSE   
 7     2 STAUR    VAN        S           FALSE   
 8     2 STAUR    CLI        S           FALSE   
 9     3 STAUR    FLC        S           FALSE   
10     3 STAUR    OXA        NA          FALSE   
11     3 STAUR    VAN        S           FALSE   
12     3 STAUR    CLI        R           FALSE   
13     4 STAUR    FLC        NA          FALSE   
14     4 STAUR    OXA        S           FALSE   
15     4 STAUR    VAN        S           FALSE   
16     4 STAUR    CLI        R           FALSE
```

---

*Data:*

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(id = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 4, 
4, 4, 4), organism = c("STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR", 
"STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR", 
"STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR", "STAUR"), antibiotic = c("FLC", "OXA", 
"VAN", "CLI", "FLC", "OXA", "VAN", "CLI", "FLC", "OXA", "VAN", 
"CLI", "FLC", "OXA", "VAN", "CLI"), sensitivity = c("R", "S", 
"S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", "S", NA, "S", "R", NA, "S", "S", 
"R")), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))
```

Comment: thanks. this suffers the same problem as previous answer from @zephryl. I have expanded the reprex as I think I made it too simple to start with.

Comment: @Ollie I see. You could actually use any logic in a `by` call. I assumed if any or all NA then it's `FALSE`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way that I think outputs what is needed.
Create a flag, `flc_oxa`, to tell whether it is a group we want. In those groups, check equality between all sensitivity values, if they are all equal assign true otherwise assign false.
Now it's a matter of taking care of the other cases (`mutate`'s 2nd instruction) and of the missing values (`mutate`'s 3rd instruction).

```r
df %>%
  mutate(flc_oxa = antibiotic %in% c("FLC", "OXA")) %>%
  group_by(id, flc_oxa) %>%
  mutate(
    mismatch = flc_oxa & all(sensitivity == sensitivity[1L]),
    mismatch = if_else(flc_oxa, mismatch, TRUE),
    mismatch = if_else(is.na(mismatch), TRUE, mismatch)
  ) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(-flc_oxa)
#> # A tibble: 16 × 5
#>       id organism antibiotic sensitivity mismatch
#>    <dbl> <chr>    <chr>      <chr>       <lgl>   
#>  1     1 STAUR    FLC        R           FALSE   
#>  2     1 STAUR    OXA        S           FALSE   
#>  3     1 STAUR    VAN        S           TRUE    
#>  4     1 STAUR    CLI        S           TRUE    
#>  5     2 STAUR    FLC        S           TRUE    
#>  6     2 STAUR    OXA        S           TRUE    
#>  7     2 STAUR    VAN        S           TRUE    
#>  8     2 STAUR    CLI        S           TRUE    
#>  9     3 STAUR    FLC        S           TRUE    
#> 10     3 STAUR    OXA        <NA>        TRUE    
#> 11     3 STAUR    VAN        S           TRUE    
#> 12     3 STAUR    CLI        R           TRUE    
#> 13     4 STAUR    FLC        <NA>        TRUE    
#> 14     4 STAUR    OXA        S           TRUE    
#> 15     4 STAUR    VAN        S           TRUE    
#> 16     4 STAUR    CLI        R           TRUE
```

<sup>Created on 2024-03-10 with [reprex v2.1.0](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>